# "[esri.WebMap] #load() Failed to load web map - ArcGIS javascript API"

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am using a webmap for one of my website. The problem is, sometimes the map is loading fne but sometimes the map failes to load leaving a console error

> [esri.WebMap] #load() Failed to load web map

```
require(["esri/WebMap", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/widgets/Search", "esri/widgets/Zoom", "esri/widgets/Locate", "esri/popup/content/ImageMediaInfo", "esri/config", "esri/portal/Portal"], function (WebMap, MapView, Search, Zoom, Locate, ImageMediaInfo, esriConfig, Portal) {
    esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://test.org/portal";

    webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: {
            id: "*********",
        },
    });

   
    var view = new MapView({
        map: webmap,
        container: "viewDiv",
        center: [-95.9406, 41.26],
        zoom: 13,
        
        basemap: "topo",
        constraints: {
            minZoom: 12,
           
        },
    });
    // webmap.loadStatus
    view.when(function () {
        webmap
            .load()
            .then(function () {
                
                return webmap.basemap.load();
            })
            .then(function () {
                
                let allLayers = webmap.allLayers;
                

                var promises = allLayers.map(function (layer) {
                    return layer.load();
                });
                return Promise.all(promises.toArray());
            })
            .then(function (layers) {
                webmap.removeAll();

                

                
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // the webmap or portal failed to load
                console.log("The resource failed to load: ", error);
            });
    });
});
```

Sometimes the map is not working because poor gis server?

These are the other console errors i get when I run the script.

> WebGL warning: drawArraysInstanced: Tex image TEXTURE_2D level 0 is incurring lazy initialization.
>
> w {name: 'worker:port-closed', details: {…}, message: "Cannot call invoke('setUpdating'), port is closed"}
>
> Object { name: "AbortError", details: undefined, message: "Aborted" }
>
> "Cannot call invoke('eventLog.onEvent'), port is closed"
>
> "Worker closing, aborting job calling 'updateSubscriptions'"
>
> f {name: 'AbortError', details: undefined, message: "Worker closing, aborting job calling 'updateSubscriptions'"}
>
> #load() Failed to load basemap (title: 'Community Map', id: '18e1c54bd14-basemap-3') TypeError: K is not a function
>
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: One way of seeing problems with connections to the services is through the network tab of the browser. There you have every request, the result, the time it takes to solve, etc. If your map server have low resources or it is over demanded, you could experience timeouts and other errors that affect the app performance.

Comment: Hi cabesuon, Thanks for the replay. Do we have any solution to ensure that the basemap won't fail to load?

Comment: @cabesuon Here are the error message when click on a point on map and expecting the popup. The popup is not appearing. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.ActionsCollection is not a constructor
    at new h (Popup.js:6:276)
    at new Features (4.29/:243:146)
    at new C (Popup.js:539:186)
    at new Popup (4.29/:243:146)
    at MapView.js:50:145

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d.ActionsCollection is not a constructor
    at new h (Popup.js:6:276)
    at new Features (4.29/:243:146)
    at new C (Popup.js:539:186)
    at new Popup (4.29/:243:146)
    at MapView.js:50:145

Comment: Hi @Adam-KER, update the question with those errors so people can follow better. Is the basemap you are using public (and can you post it here)?, is that the only service you are having issues with?.

Comment: Hi Cabesuon, I am using the portal url. 'esriConfig.portalUrl = "https://dcgis.org/portal"; ' and a webmap id. I  think which is public.